# c++ is there a way to copy priority queue elements into a vector so it can be iterated to check for duplicates

Tags: c++

I am attempting to write an A* search in c++ for the first time but i have written them in Java before.

I am having trouble checking if something is already in the openList or not. The OpenList is a priority_queue of Node's, but i understanding you cannot simply iterate through a priority queue.

My idea is that, i pass the openList to a function, which will copy the elements into a temp vector and then i can iterate this temp vector. This is obviously not good for extremely fast and efficient run times, but i can't think of another way around it.

The closed list is very simple as you can see just iterate through the vector.

These are the two lists:

```
priority_queue<Node, vector<Node>, NodeCompare> openList;
vector<Node> closedList;
```

code:

```
bool checkInClosedList(std::vector<Node>& v,int x, int y){

    for (std::vector<Node>::iterator iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); ++iter) {
        if(iter->getX() == x && iter->getY() == y){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;

}
```

How can i do the above, but for a `priority_queue <Node, vector<Node>, NodeCompare>`?

The priority queue itself works fine i have tested it, but my A* gets stuck in infinite loops because it keeps checking Nodes it has already checked!

Cheers,
Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a std::list and call [unique()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/unique/) on it. In addition a std::list lets you [sort based on a predicate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/) which would allow you to emulate any sorting that the priority_queue is doing.

Alternately a std::map enforces unique keys and will remove duplicates.

Comment: thanks a bunch, that has saved me a lot of hastle, just need to get the sort working.

Comment: Glad to hear! Most of the time if you are struggling with a standard container, it means there may be a better one. Often it is tricky to know which is best for a given problem.

Comment: Thanks Jack, in Java it was much simplier i didn't know about the list container!

Comment: Yes, but why `std::list`? It doesn't seem like the best choice.

Comment: A list is ideal because it meets the two needs I gathered from Chris' post that he needed. 1) Enforce uniqueness and 2) maintain the same sorting behavior of a priority queue.

Answer (score 3):

The underlying data container is a protected member of
`std::priority_queue`, so you can access it in a derived class.
If you want to add pre- or post-conditions or invariants, this
is the correct solution; you derive your own class which
enforces the invariants.